# zipcodes within a specific radius

Tags: sql, ms-access, latitude-longitude, zipcode, great-circle

I'm looking for an SQL query to let me retrieve Zipcodes within a specific radius.

I have a table called `tblZip` with columns: `Zipcode`, `Lat`(latitude), `Long`(Longitude).

```
tblZip

Zipcode    | Lat    | Long
Short Text | Number | Number
```

I have checked few other answers that suggest use of [Great-circle Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) but I don't seem to understand how it works.  I get a headache just seeing all the conversions from / to radians and degrees and I really tried to understand it, but I'm so bad with mathematics.

I appreciate your help and guidance.

PS: I'm using a Microsoft Access Database.

Comment: Will you be calculating the distance between two records or between one record and an arbitrary point?  If the former, then how do you choose the two points?

Comment: I'm calculating distance between a specific record and all the other records in the table tblZip.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the haversine distance formula in a VBA function (borrowed [here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/calculating-mileage-distance-in-excel-and-access/)). Then have it called in your SQL query. And even have your query filtered by distance with `WHERE` clause per your needs. Do note: this solution will only work inside the MSAccess.exe program. You will not be able to call it externally via ODBC/OLEDB.

And since you need comparison geocodes, SQL query below uses a cross join where each record is compared with every other record in table. Additionally, query avoids reverse duplicates and same-matched pairings reducing the size. But be careful if table is large as cross joins on self returns N<sup>2</sup> records, that is before the filtering of duplicates.

**SQL**  *(Zipcode pairings with distance of 5 km or less)*

```
SELECT z1.Zipcode, z2.Zipcode, 
       GetDistance(z1.Lat, z1.Lon, z2.Lat, z2.Lon) As km_distance
FROM tblZip z1, tblZip z2
WHERE z1.Zipcode > z2.Zipcode
AND GetDistance(s1.lat, s1.lon, s1.lat, s2.lon) <= 5;
```

**VBA** *(save in a standalone module)*

```vb
Function GetDistance(lat1Degrees As Double, lon1Degrees As Double, lat2Degrees As Double, lon2Degrees As Double) As Double

    Dim earthSphereRadiusKilometers As Double
    Dim kilometerConversionToMilesFactor As Double
    Dim lat1Radians As Double
    Dim lon1Radians As Double
    Dim lat2Radians As Double
    Dim lon2Radians As Double
    Dim AsinBase As Double
    Dim DerivedAsin As Double

    'Mean radius of the earth (replace with 3443.89849 to get nautical miles)
    earthSphereRadiusKilometers = 6371

    'Convert kilometers into miles (replace 0.621371 with 1 to keep in kilometers)
    kilometerConversionToMilesFactor = 0.621371

    'Convert each decimal degree to radians
    lat1Radians = (lat1Degrees / 180) * (4 * ATN(1))
    lon1Radians = (lon1Degrees / 180) * (4 * ATN(1))
    lat2Radians = (lat2Degrees / 180) * (4 * ATN(1))
    lon2Radians = (lon2Degrees / 180) * (4 * ATN(1))

    AsinBase = Sin(Sqr(Sin((lat1Radians - lat2Radians) / 2) ^ 2 + Cos(lat1Radians) * Cos(lat2Radians) * Sin((lon1Radians - lon2Radians) / 2) ^ 2))
    DerivedAsin = (AsinBase / Sqr(-AsinBase * AsinBase + 1))

    'Get distance from [lat1,lon1] to [lat2,lon2]
    GetMiles = Round(2 * DerivedAsin * (earthSphereRadiusKilometers * kilometerConversionToMilesFactor), 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer above. It does exactly what I want. However, the calculations are not giving a precise result. For example I tried two zipcodes '00501' and '00705', the GetMiles function gave me 1628.4 miles while few online tools to calculate distance between zipcodes gave me 1619.2 and 1617.87. Do you have any idea how to get a more precise result?

Comment: Possibly it is due to the pi decimal precision. Try changing the 3.14### constant with `(4 * ATN(1))`. See edit. And note this function returns km not miles.

Comment: It didn't change a thing. But never mind it anyway. However, executing this query "SELECT TOP 100 tblZip.Zipcode, tblZip.City, tblZip.Lat, tblZip.Lon, GetDistance(40.81,-73.04,tblZip.Lat,tblZip.[Lon]) AS Distance
FROM tblZip
Where GetDistance(40.81,-73.04,tblZip.Lat,tblZip.[Lon])<4
;" is resulting in "Data Type Mismatch" error. I don't know why but I found out that the GetDistance() is the problem. By the way, I changed the last line of the stored procedure from GetMiles to GetDistance.

Comment: By looking at query, I can't see why you get that error. Be sure *Lat* and *Lon* are numeric data types and not string. Also, I edited that last line too and note this is not a stored procedure but an SQL call to a VBA function.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have found that Lat,Lon of some of the records in my table are empty and GetMiles is what's causing the problem of datatype mismatch because it is doing all the math on empty variable. I have tried to add a test If IsNull(Lat1Degrees) Then GetMiles = 999999 else Do the math. But now, that test is being evaluated as False even with the records that have empty Lat, Lon. Any idea for how to alter GetMiles to test for empty/null values from it's arguments before doing the math?

Comment: Where are you placing the `If` statement? It should go to very beginning after `Dim` statements. Also, you can try SQL conditional: `IIF([Lat] IS NOT NULL AND [Lon] IS NOT NULL, GetDistance(...), NULL) As Distance` and do same in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you again Parfait, I have figured another way to get rid on Null values. IsNull() did not work for me.